# Probability of discrete Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stan

I am modelling some time-series data as a discrete Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (not sure if this terminology is correct):

$$X[t+1] = X[t] + \theta(mean-X[t]) + \epsilon$$

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$$

I want to know the probability of the distribution in the future to exceed some threshold $U$:
$$Pr(X[t+k] \geq U\mid X[t]),\,k = 1..\infty$$

I can solve this problem with Stan, but it is too slow because I have to simulate a lot of future possibilities $k$ for every time-step $t$.

Is there a closed formula for this problem? Just pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as $\theta <1$, this is a standard autoregressive model of order one, with "drift" (constant term) and normal i.i.d. errors. So the process will have a normal distribution. All you need to do is find the variance.

Comment: Thank you @AlecosPapadopoulos, I had overlooked this basic fact. Now I've found plenty of literature about the variance of forecasting in AR models.